# How to create trigger on update with condition based on old and new data?

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I want to update field `server_prev_level_xp` when 
`NEW.server_xp > OLD.server_prev_level_xp`

I use MariaDb and his [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/trigger-overview/).

I try this but it doesn't work :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Level_Update
AFTER UPDATE OF server_xp ON servers
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.server_xp > OLD.server_prev_level_xp)
BEGIN
    SET NEW.server_prev_level_xp = OLD.server_prev_level_xp + OLD.server_prev_level_xp >> 1;
    SET NEW.server_level = OLD.server_level + 1;
END;
```

Have an error on line 4:

```
WHEN (NEW.server_xp > OLD.server_prev_level_xp)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please clarify with table schema and exact error information.

Comment: `IF ` (NEW.server_xp > OLD.server_prev_level_xp) ?

Comment: What error? Why change the value AFTER the update?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax used to create the trigger doesn't apply to MariaBD (`[OF <trigger Column list>]` and `FOR EACH ROW [WHEN (search condition)]`). See [CREATE TRIGGER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-trigger/).

One option is to use [IF Statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-statement/).

**Remember:** `Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger because the row change will have already occurred.`.

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `Level_Update` /*AFTER*/ BEFORE UPDATE ON `servers`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.`server_xp` > OLD.`server_prev_level_xp` THEN
  .
  .
  .
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `Level_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON shp_servers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`server_xp` > OLD.`server_level_xp` THEN
        SET NEW.`server_level_xp` = OLD.`server_level_xp` + OLD.`server_level_xp` >> 1;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Have :

## 1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

And try :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Level_Update` BEFORE UPDATE ON shp_servers
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.`server_xp` > OLD.`server_level_xp` THEN
            SET NEW.`server_level_xp` = OLD.`server_level_xp` + OLD.`server_level_xp` >> 1;
        END IF;
    END
```

Have :

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; at line 5